# What should search method return if nothing found?

Tags: javascript

I have this method

```
var link = this.find_first_link(selectedElem);
```

which should return an object. I'm not sure what should it return if no element is found - null, undefined or false? I've rejected 'false' option since I don't think it suits here so I'm choosing betwen null or undefined. I've read that 'undefined' should be used where some kind of exception or error occurs, so currently this method returns null. Is that OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at what is done in methods you have in your browser.

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns `null` when there is no element with the id provided.

That's what `null` has been designed for : to represent the absence of an object (`typeof null` is `"object"`). Use it when the expected returned type is `"object"` but you have no object to return. It's better than `undefined` here because you would have `undefined` before you even decided what to put in the variable or before you even call the function.

From [the description of null in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) :

> In APIs, null is often retrieved in place where an object can be
>   expected but no object is relevant.

Yes, use `null`.

Comment: As a side note, return null if your function should return one thing but don't return null if your function should return an array of things. For functions that return arrays, if nothing is found then an empty array should be returned instead. I've seen lots of code where null is returned in such cases and it always leads to stupid `!=null` check before for loops.

Comment: Good suggestion to look on existing APIs if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

var link = this.find_first_link(selectedElem);

It will return NULL.

Comment: The OP is asking what his method, `find_first_link`, should return if there is no result; not what it *does* return currently.